# CRONJOB not running the .sh file

Tags: linux, cron, putty

I am accessing my linus box from putty.I have a Java Progaram packed in a Jar File. I have made a scheduler.sh file that sets Java Path and execute the Java Program.SO far everything is good when i run the Scheduler.sh, the Java programs runs.

The content of the Scheduler.sh is

```
 #!/bin/sh
> echo "The Script Starts now!!!!!!!!!!"
> 
> export JAVA_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/java/java64/jrockit-jdk1.6.0_29
> export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH cd
> /u01/CRM/softwaredepot/jarfiles/
> 
> java -jar EPALS_Linux.jar
> 
> echo "The Script ends now!!!!!!!!!!"
```

Now I want to execute this using CRONJOB.So I added this to CONJOB

```
[sankalp@elb1cn11 ~]$ crontab -e
53 13 * * * /u01/CRM/softwaredepot/Scheduler.sh>tester.log

~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
"/tmp/crontab.XXXXU8TrO9" 2L, 64C
```

Nothing happend.But when i executed this line(mentioned in the crontab

/u01/CRM/softwaredepot/Scheduler.sh>tester.log
it ran successfully.So it means the entry in the crotab is also correct.Then why is it not executing.Kindly help me

Answer (score 2):

You don't specify what you run the script with. e.g `bash` or `sh`

```
53 13 * * * bash /u01/CRM/softwaredepot/Scheduler.sh>tester.log
```

Since you have specified, the shebang in the start : `#!/bin/sh` it should automatically run with sh, so it could be permissions.  It does have not the right to execute.

```
run chmod +x shcripname.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be the working directory problem.

53 13 * * * cd /path/to/the/working/dir/; /u01/CRM/softwaredepot/Scheduler.sh>tester.log